# curl: (35) gnutls_handshake() failed: Public key signature verification has failed

Tags: curl, debian, gnutls

I have an issue, when Im doing curl request or git push, that show me

> curl: (35) gnutls_handshake() failed: Public key signature verification has failed.

curl --version

> curl 7.50.1 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.50.1 GnuTLS/3.5.3 zlib/1.2.8 libidn/1.33 libssh2/1.7.0 nghttp2/1.14.0 librtmp/2.3
>   Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtmp rtsp scp sftp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp 
>   Features: AsynchDNS IDN IPv6 Largefile GSS-API Kerberos SPNEGO NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP HTTP2 UnixSockets

I have already done: update and downgrade curl to version 7.38 but this do not help me.
Sorry for my English, tnx.

Answer (score 19):

```
dpkg -l | grep libgnutls

ii  libgnutls-deb0-28:amd64              3.3.8-6+deb8u3              amd64        GNU TLS library - main runtime library
ii  libgnutls-openssl27:amd64            3.3.8-6+deb8u3              amd64        GNU TLS library - OpenSSL wrapper
ii  libgnutls30:amd64                    3.5.7-2                     amd64        GNU TLS library - main runtime library

sudo apt-get remove --purge libgnutls-deb0-28
```

... worked for me.

Comment: This `apt-get remove` command proposes removing 256 packages for me, including many things I use...

Comment: I removed everything expect `libgnutls30:amd64` and it was working again.

Answer (score 3):

After downgrading to curl 7.38.0, I also had to downgrade:

```
$ sudo apt-mark hold libcurl3-gnutls
$ sudo apt-get install libcurl3-gnutls=7.38.0-4+deb8u4
```

Then the error went away.
I'm on debian jessie.

Answer (score 1):

downgrade the curl to 7.38.0 will work for https url

first you can try to remove curl by apt-get,in fact apt-get can not remove all dependences!  then use aptitude to install curl 7.38.0, pls see below commands

**apt-get remove --auto-remove curl**

**aptitude install curl=7.38.0-4+deb8u4**

The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

```
 Keep the following packages at their current version:
```

1)     curl [Not Installed]

Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] **n**

The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

```
 Install the following packages:
```

1)     libcurl3 [7.38.0-4+deb8u4 (stable)]
Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] **y**

Answer (score 1):

I had to downgrade libcurl3 and curl as well

```
sudo apt-get install libcurl3-gnutls=7.38.0-4+deb8u4 curl=7.38.0-4+deb8u4 libcurl3=7.38.0-4+deb8u4
```

```

works also on Debian Testing.. needed to downgrade to Jessie's libcurl3